# Angular validation issue

Tags: angularjs, validation

I've got an issue with the Angular validation classes. I've got three classes in my css with three different images, that shows if the field is required, if the user has filled in correct or not. E.g. I have one input field where the user types in a personal number, and I look it up in a service and fills the model with firstname, lastname, address etc. which also populates the input fields.

I made a simple example

HTML

```
<div ng-app="ebu" ng-controller="search">
<button id="search-apparentice" ng-click="addName()">Search apprentice</button>
<hr>    
<input id="username" type="text" ng-model="user.name" required>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('ebu', []).
controller('search', function($scope) {
$scope.user = {};
$scope.addName = function()
{
$scope.user.name = "Kasper";
}
})
```

CSS

```
input[required].ng-invalid  
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}


input[required].ng-valid 
{
    border: 1px solid green;
}

input[required].ng-pristine
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[FiddleJS][1][1]: http://jsfiddle.net/kaspergantzhorn/z1wg6tko/9/

Comment: Can you include the code on how are you 'injecting' the city into the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still pristine because pristine means it has never had focus.  The user is not clicking on it, therefore it never gets dirty.  If this isn't a user-modified field, pristine is not the right thing to use.

Additionally, in the ng-change of the input, you should be able to use $setDirty.

```
<input type="text" ng-change="formName.inputName.$setDirty()" />
```

For you code above:

```
<div ng-app="ebu" ng-controller="search">
<button id="search-apparentice" ng-click="addName(); myForm.name.$setDirty()">Search apprentice</button>
<hr> 
<form name="myForm">   
<input name="name" id="username" type="text" ng-model="user.name" required>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Well I'm updating the model, so you are right, the input field is not touched or focused. The example I used was also a bad example. The core issue is, when I update the model and there by the input field, how do I force the validation helper classes to change? Do I need to write my own validation? And do you have any good tuts or examples?

Comment: You can probably do it right in the DOM, but it would help to see your HTML.

Comment: I just added an example

Comment: You can use the answer I supplied above to dirty the input when you click the button.  Add a form tag with a name and give the input a name and use use the ng-change attr in the input like I have above.  Should add the ng-dirty tag when you click the button and it inserts the name.

Comment: OK try it now.  It didn't like the $setDirty in ng-change, so I put it in the button and confirmed it works correctly.